# "живой поиск" отправляет запрос при каждом нажатии

Tags: javascript

```js
 function debounce(callback, wait, context = this) {
  let timeout = null 
  let callbackArgs = null
  
  const later = () => callback.apply(context, callbackArgs)
  
  return function() {
    callbackArgs = arguments
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
  }
}
   $('.who').bind("change keyup input click", function() {


const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "search.php", 
                data: {'search':this.value},
                response: 'text',
                success: function(data){
                    $(".search_result").html(data).fadeIn(); /
                }
            }) ;  
}, 1000)
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', handleScroll)
   
        
    })
```

что то не получается с задержкой. ввожу символы, после этого задержка 1 сек и отправляется куча запросов. а мне надо что бы одним запросом все введенные символы

Answer (score 0):

```js
const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
var search=$("#search").val();
   $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "search.php",
                data: {'search':search},
                response: 'text',
                success: function(data){
$(".search_result").html(data);
                }
            }) ;
}, 1000);
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', handleScroll)
```